# If f is twice differenetiable at a and g is twice differentiable at $f(a)$ then prove..

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

$(f\circ g)''(a)= g'((f(a))(f''(a)+ g''(f(a))(f'(a))^2$

This looks like a product rule but I am not sure how to justify it and I don't know where the $(f'(a))^2$ came from

Comment: You simply have to apply chain rule twice and the product rule in the second derivation once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the chain rule combined with the product rule, see:
$$ (f\circ g)'(a) = f'(g(a)) \cdot g'(a)$$
and 
\begin{eqnarray} 
(f \circ g)''(a) &=& \bigl(f'(g(a)) \cdot g'(a)\bigr)' \\
& = & (f'(g(a)))' \cdot g'(a) + f'(g(a)) \cdot g''(a) \\
& = & f''(g(a)) \cdot (g'(a))^{2} + f'(g(a)) \cdot g''(a)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: although the final answer is tupposed fo have f(a)^2 not g'(a)^2

Comment: This is because you asked for the derivative of $g \circ f$ and I did the calculation with $f \circ g$, sorry, my bad.

Comment: okay because i am struggling to get it. so far i got g(f(a))'' * f'(a)

Comment: It's exactly the same calculation. I won't edit the answer, try to understand the prove and, if you need, follow the same steps to get the result for $(g \circ f)''$